# Could I add an item in `/etc/fstab` to bind an old directory with a new one?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount, automount

I have a problem with binding two directories. The problem comes that storage on hard disk is almost run out and I install another disk moving files in `~/Documents/` into one folder of the new disk. I still want `mount --bind folder_on_new_disk ~/Documents`, thus I will not change my favor.

The problem is that could I add an item in `/etc/fstab` to achieve this automatically when system startup?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add this to `fstab` as follows:

```
/mnt/new_disk/folder /home/[username]/Documents    none    bind    0 0
```

Replace the correct folder name, and the username where the documents folder is.  It also presumes the /home directory is where your user folders are, so adjust accordingly if not.

Answer (score 6):

[@Paul's fstab example](https://superuser.com/a/429925/53590) is, basically, the way to go if you want an answer to the question as asked. **However**, I would suggest that unless you have specific reasons for only moving your documents, it might not be a bad idea to move the whole `/home` directory to the new disk, and use the same technique to bind /home to its new location (or even just move /home/* to the root of a partition on the new drive and mount that partition at /home). This will provide two major benefits:

1. You are likely to get more space for your home directory.
2. You completely separate the operating system, system-wide configuration files and application binaries from your own files.

The point on separation to me is the bigger issue: it means that if you need to reinstall the OS for some reason, you won't have to worry anywhere near as much about your personal files (e-mails, documents, music, etc etc).

Unix mount points are a very flexible construct - do take advantage of that.